# Access to the clipboard when copying content from a WebControl with a Silverlight-component in VB6

Tags: silverlight, vb6, browser

Little old school :)

In VB6, I got a UserControl containing a SHDocVwCtl.WebBrowser. The page I am displaying contains a Silverlight-component, and I want to be able to copy content (text) from the SL to the clipboard. For some reason this doesn't work out-of-the-box.

I searched the web and found a method for copying text from a html-page to the clipboard, using this command:

```
WebBrowser.ExecWB OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
```

I was hoping that this would also work for copying content from SilverLight, but alas.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you copy it from silverlight manually? If not, you're probably completely out of luck.

Comment: Be sure to look at http://forums.silverlight.net/p/118806/267618.aspx which says you cannot distribute SilverLight. This makes it a very poor choice for use in applications.

Comment: Also see http://forums.silverlight.net/t/208104.aspx

Comment: @BobRiemersma: Our application is displaying a (external) webpage containing SilverLight, so we don't need to distribute Silverlight as it already is installed as browser-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Most operations that represent security risks (including file access and clipboard access) are restricted in Silverlight.

I gather you are trying to copy the web page and include Silverlight content from a SL control on that page? If so, forget it. Silverlight effectively renders as a bitmap into the webpage (just like Flash).

*There is some limited support for clipboard copy/paste in Silverlight, but needs to be user triggered, so is unlikely to do what you seem to want.*

Comment: Not sure if you have understood what I want - or if I understand what you think I want. :) Simply put; I want the Silverlight clipboard "transfered" to the Windows clipboard. I already capture the Copy-event in my application - all I need is access to the SL-clipboard.

Comment: Ah, I think I now understand what you understand about my understanding :) No you can't programmatically access the SL clipboard from outside of SL. The transfer is *pull from* and *push to* system clipboard.